# pandas.read_sql_query - how to write correctly WHERE condition if both the column name and searched value contain space

Tags: python, sql, pandas, psycopg2

I write the SQL query like this

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE "Performance Score" = "Needs Improvement";', conn)
```

```
hr_dataset - table
Performance Score - column
Needs Improvement - searched value
```

Both column name and searched value contain a space, that's why I have to use quotes, but this query results with an error.

```
**DatabaseError**: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE "Performance Score" = "Needs Improvement";': column "Needs Improvement" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE "Performance Score" = "Needs Imp...
```

How should I write such query correctly?

Comment: Please Tag the Database (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL ...)

Comment: It might be a good idea to add the error that you get when running this query.

Answer (score 0):

if it is SQL Server

```
SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE [Performance Score] like '%Needs Improvement%'
```

if it is MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE `Performance Score` like '%Needs Improvement%'
```

if it is PostgresSQL, try

```
SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE "Performance Score" like '%Needs Improvement%'
```

See the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=627d91a92bc0184be944a21e6ab0ce9f) for PostgresSQL

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, **'Needs Improvement'** is mentioned in double quotes where database considers it as a column name

```
SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE Performance Score = 'Needs Improvement';
```